# Excel Workbook_BeforeClose function crashes other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a little function below to save some data whenever I close this spreadsheet. But if I have multiple spreadsheets open, Excel will crash once I close the one with "Workbook_BeforeClose" function. Anyone has seen similar issues? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim current_sht1 As Worksheet
Dim FilePath As String
Dim shtName1 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FilePath = "C:\Users\DLW\Test1\Local_datafile.xlsx"
shtName1 = "Tab1"

Set current_sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName1)

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Set sht1 = wb.Worksheets(shtName1)

sht1.Cells.Clear

current_sht1.UsedRange.Copy
sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 ThisWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Saved to local file."

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code but with a full file path for `FilePath` and nothing froze/closed on me.

Answer (score 1):

Your "FilePath" isn't an actual path, it's just the name of the workbook you want to open.
To open a closed workbook, you need an actual path like

> "C:\Users\DLW\Test1\Local_datafile.xlsx"

If it's in the same folder as ThisWorkbook, you can use

```
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Local_datafile.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the path link just for privacy issue. Edited my question to make it more clear. It still crashes other spreadsheets. I also disabled all my third party add-ins and it still crashes... Not sure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you go through your code line by line to see where it causes an issue? I just tested your code with a testfile and it worked just fine. Is there a sheet protected? Are you sure both sheets are named the same?